# Accessing firestore data at a global scope

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access the firestore data and push it to an array. This is super basic but for some reason I cannot figure out why this isn't working:

```
var db = admin.firestore();

let arr = [];

var Ref = db.collection('Test').doc('Document');
var getDoc = Ref.get()
    .then(doc => {
       if (!doc.exists) {
         console.log('No such document!');
       } else {
          let data = doc.data().Name;
          arr.push(data);
       }
    })
    .catch(err => {
         console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });

 console.log(arr)  // expecting >>> ['Joe'] (ie: data that is in firestore object)
```

Why doesn't `arr` contain the firestore object?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't contain the data from firestore *yet*.

The `get()` operates asynchronously by returning a Promise and then continuing program execution. The next line is the `console.log(arr)`, but `arr` isn't populated yet - it is populated when the Promise completes (calls the `then()` part).

If you're using a sufficiently modern version of node (node 8 and up, which you should be using at this point), then you can use `await` to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete before continuing to the next line.

I haven't tested it, but your code might look something like this after a rewrite:

```
doc = await Ref.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
   let data = doc.data().Name;
   arr.push(data);
}

console.log(arr)
```

This will work because the `await` waits for the async `get()` to complete and return the doc. The rest of it is processed synchronously.